# importing com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder

Tags: android, jar, package

I installed the jar file ormlite-android-4.19 but Android studio can't import com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder. 
What jar file does com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder need?
Please help

Comment: How did you added the jar file? Rebuild the project once and after that try to import it.

Comment: - drag and drop into libs folder
-after rebuilding the project, Android studio still can't import it

Comment: Add it lover here: File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies

Comment: @PrerakSola the same error is here: Error:(112, 29) error: cannot find symbol method getRuntimeExceptionDao(Class<Runner>)
Android studio can't import com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder

Comment: After commenting the line using ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder, I have this error : minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 11 declared in library

Answer (score 0):

*QueryBuilder to construct custom queries*

In **build.gradle** (module app):

```
dependencies {
    ..
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.1'
    ..
}
```

**Reference:**

- https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android
- http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.j256.ormlite%7Cormlite-android%7C5.1%7C
- http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#QueryBuilder-Basics

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.